# Changing a 26 character string column to timestamp in SQL for Athena Query

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-athena

I have the following data stream under "mycolumn".

1996-02-14-02.28.37.404000

1996-02-14-02.28.37.404001

1996-02-14-02.28.37.418000

1996-02-16-02.53.00.248000

1996-02-16-02.53.00.265000

How can I use a SQL **where** statement on Athena to select values between to two dates. I attempted the following but failed.

select * from "mytable" 

 where mycolumn > to_char('YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MIN.SS.zzzzzz', '1996-02-14-02.28.37.404000') 

and mycolumn < to_char('yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mi.ss.zzzzzz', '1996-02-16- 02.53.00.265000')

**SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:20: Unexpected parameters (varchar(27), varchar(26)) for function to_char. Expected: to_char(timestamp with time zone, varchar)**

or

select * from "mytable" 

 where "mycolumn" 

 between TIMESTAMP '1996-02-14-02.28.37.404000' 

  and  TIMESTAMP '1996-02-16-02.53.00.265000'; 

 **SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:9: '1996-02-14-02.28.37.404000' is not a valid timestamp literal**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_parse()` to convert your text timestamps into bona fide timestamps, and then use a range comparison with valid timestamp literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE DATE_PARSE(mycolumn, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') > timestamp '1996-02-14 02:28:37.404' AND
      DATE_PARSE(mycolumn, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') < timestamp '1996-02-16 02:53:00.265';
```

But note that it would be better to not store timestamps as plain text.  If you instead use a proper timestamp column, then we don't need the ugly calls to `date_parse()` to write your query.

Comment: I got the following error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:54: '1996-02-14 02:28:37.404000' is not a valid timestamp literal

Comment: Try the updated version above with just 3 decimal microseconds.

Comment: There is still a problem: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:54: '1996-02-14-02:28:37.404' is not a valid timestamp literal

Comment: My code shouldn't be generating this error AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, I got it correct on 3 decimal places

Comment: While the code works well on Athena it does not query well on Oracle DB. It gives an error further: ORA-00904: "DATE_PARSE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier". MAy you assist further.

Comment: You tagged with Athena, if you need an answer on Oracle, you should ask a new question.